# JUnit 4 result to XML transformation

Tags: xml, junit, junit4, transformation

I have been trying to write code to generate the XML output from a Junit Result object using the standard schema for Junit reports.

I am triggering my tests using Junit 4, hence I am using a JunitCore instance to execute my tests. So, it will not make sense in my case to duplicate the execution by using a JunitTask instance.

I am over-riding the testRunfinished(Result) method available in Junit4. I want to write the transformation logic here so that it generates the XML which can then be viewed using the standard XSLT.

One way would be to write a transformer which creates a document object and then programmatically add nodes and hence create the XML. But this would hardwire the report strcture.

All the classes exposed by Ant seem to work with Junit3 and does not seem to separate the concerns of executing tests and reporting results, hence they force execution (XMLResultAggregator).

1. Is there a standard way of doing this? A library exposed by Ant or Junit?
2. Is there an alternative approach (Ant is not an option for me)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not generating standalone HTML with CSS in header reports? Or even plain txt reporst.

I generated my XML reports with a Template which I copied and then filled in the fields with a Java xml framework.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
```

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, it is one of the brute force options, but as I mentioned, it would hard-wire the report structure to my transformer. I am curios if there is an API which exposes methods to transform a Result object from Junit to the XML document.